# How would you express the verb "to other (someone/something)" in German?

Tags: translation

Here's the sentance I just wrote in English:

- *Focus on the human as a way of demonstrating the stupidity of othering homeless people.*

I am wondering how one would best translate the concept of othering people?

Definition via Merriam-Webster:

> to treat or consider (a person or a group of people) as alien to oneself or one's group (as because of different racial, sexual, or cultural characteristics)

My best translation would be:

- *Konzentriert sich auf die menschliche Gemeinsamkeit, sodass die Dummheit, Obdachloser zu anderen, ist demonstriert.*

*Zu anderen* is the closest I could come: "to other" isn't dealt with in German dictionaries.

Comment: Google translator tells me othering=ausgrenzen but I neither can't find that verb, nor the noun in other dictionaries. How common is it?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/ausgrenzen

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=1453443&idForum=2&lang=de&lp=ende

Comment: With questions like these, it can often be helpful to first translate into, say 1980‘s English, and into German from there.

Comment: The word "othering" isn't the only issue in your attempt to translate the sentence. The translation isn't intelligible to me, no matter which word you substitute for "othering". (But also the original doesn't seem to be a complete sentence, unless it's in the imperative mood.) Perhaps it would be best to first reconsider what exactly you want to convey before attempting the translation.

Comment: Note: the verb you are translating is not really an *English* word per se, it is a *technical term* from the field of sociology. Therefore, it also makes sense to not look for a *German* word, but for a technical term in sociology. And it would not actually surprise me to find out that German sociologists simply borrow the English term.

Comment: The sentence is from my journal: therefore, I took liberties with grammar.

Comment: How about _entmenschlichen_?

Comment: And the whole sentence could become "Konzentriere auf die Menschlichkeit, um die Ausgrenzung von Obdachlosen als Dummheit zu entlarven."

Comment: @JörgWMittag : "ausgrenzen" has a long history in Germany

Comment: @JörgWMittag If one simply borrows the English word, how does one inflect it --- simply as in English, or does one get forms like "geothert"?  (This is not as silly as it may sound.  In my field, set theory, "forcing" is a technical term, it's usually unchanged in German, and I've seen "geforct".)

Comment: @AndreasBlass: However one wants, basically :-D I have seen both "downgeloadet" and "gedownloadet", for example, and both "upgedated" and "geupdatet". There is no set rule for loan words. Typically, their assimilation status changes over time, and they become inflected more and more like native words the more time passes.

Answer (score 23):

The fitting word for this is *ausgrenzen*. It corresponds very precisely to your English expression.

Comment: I would say it works here, but does not match as precisely as you said. to other is more internally, in thought etc , while ausgrenzen somewhat implies action, or the inclination for action